# How to get touch events (X and Y coordinates) using Service class in Android?

Tags: android, class, events, service, touch

I am going to develop application where i need TouchEvents to be used in the Android Service class. I have tried to search on the internet but not able to find the proper solution.

Basically Service class should listen whatever touch events occurs into the whole device and it should display the X and Y co-ordinates of any of the application which is being used by the Device.

I don't want to use Activity but only Service class should be used and give all of the events happen outside of the application.

Can anybody help me out with source code for service class usage for getting Touch events and get the other applications touch events into service class ?

please share useful information or any link for further implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is actually a way. But you will need a rooted device. And from what I got so far you need to have some kind of view. It can be a very little box. I do not know if it will work with a box of size 0x0 tho.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already find out it is not possible. It would be very serious security flaw if you were able to do something like that. Application obtaining coordinates of all touch events (including ones from password input) is a keyloger. I, as an android device user, am glad it is not possible.